# Unable to connect to tableau server using TableauServerClient python library

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am trying to sign into TSC with the following:

```
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(name, password, site_id=site_id)
server = TSC.Server('http://10az.online.tableau.com', use_server_version=True)
print(server.version)
# Sign in
server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth);
```

I am getting this error message. I have never got this message before when trying to sign into the server with TSC
`SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10az.online.tableau.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.4/serverInfo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))`

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC

import logging

import time


def refresh_tableau_workbook(**kwargs):

    # user_name: You can log in to your account or you can log in to your personal account
    # password: login password
    # site_name: tableau site name （Our production one is empty by default）
    # server_version: Version 2.8 or greater is currently supported
    # workbook_name:The workbook name that needs to be refreshed
    # server_public:Tableau Server URL
    # sleep_time: How often is the query refreshed
    # number_of_queries: The number of times the query has been flushed
    user_name = kwargs.get('user_name')
    password = kwargs.get('password')
    site_name = kwargs.get('site_name')
    server_version = kwargs.get('server_version')
    workbook_name = kwargs.get('workbook_name')
    server_public = kwargs.get('server_public')
    number_of_queries = kwargs.get('number_of_queries')
    sleep_time = kwargs.get('sleep_time')
    tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(user_name, password, site_name)
    server = TSC.Server(server_public)
    server.add_http_options({'verify': False})
    server.version = server_version
    info = """No workbook refresh can be found within the query times. Suggestions are as follows: 
    1. Increase the query times,
    2. Increase the interval time,
    3. Manually go to Tableau to check whether the report is refreshed
    """
    with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
        all_workbooks_items, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get()
        for workbook in all_workbooks_items:
            # Matches whether the workbook name is the report we need to refresh
            if workbook.name == workbook_name:
                # The last time the report was refreshed
                last_update = str(workbook.updated_at)[0:19]
                logging.info("nearest workbook refresh datetime is: {}".format(last_update))
                logging.info("begin refresh workbook:{}".format(workbook_name))
                # The program to refresh the report is started
                # server.workbooks.refresh(server.workbooks.get_by_id(workbook.id))
                now_update = ''
                # The circular query is all report refresh success
                for i in range(0, number_of_queries + 1):
                    all_workbooks_item_temp, pagination_item_temp = server.workbooks.get()
                    for workbook_temp in all_workbooks_item_temp:
                        # Matches whether the workbook name is the report we need to refresh
                        if workbook_temp.name == workbook_name:
                            # Last report refresh time
                            now_update = str(workbook_temp.updated_at)[0:19]
                    # The refresh time is longer than the previous one, which means the refresh is successful
                    if now_update > last_update:
                        logging.info("the last workbook refresh datetime is: {}".format(now_update))
                        logging.info("{} workbook refresh success!".format(workbook_name))
                        break
                    elif i < number_of_queries:
                        # logging.info the number of queries that successfully flush the log
                        logging.info("{}、this workbook is refreshing...".format(i+1))
                        # If the refresh is not successful, take a break to continue the query
                        time.sleep(sleep_time)
                    else:
                        logging.info(info)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When answering a question, explain what your code does and why it solves the OP's problem.